# Data retention in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

Is there a way to add retention on PostgreSQL? I've tried partitioning but seems to be a problem when querying between multiple partitioning regarding performance. This seemed to be a better way because you can delete one partition in a fast way then deleting few years of data.

Comment: First of all: do not ask two, loosely related questions in one SO post. Make them into two SO questions. Secondly: partitioning is a good approach. What exactly do you mean by performance problem? Did you measure how the performance degrades?

Answer (score -1):

Partitioning is the king's way for getting rid of old data.

Most of your queries will get slightly slower, but that shouldn't be too bad if you use a moderate number of partitions.

Comment: Partitioning can be done automatically? It is a tool that can do this?

Comment: There is `pg_partman`, but nothing out of the box. A simple `cron` job on the database server might do the trick.